# Choosing my first Domain Registrar?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-registration

This will be the first domain i've ever registered. So i'm at a loss what to look for. I definitely don't want to go with GoDaddy.

Here are my requirements:

1. Must have unlimited email forwards for my domain
2. Easy to transfer away if i choose.
3. Must not be one of those shady registrars that will try to auction your domain at the end.
4. Ability to create sub domains
5. Domain Registration is Private
6. I would like a domain registrar that would let me use my dynamic ip of my ISP (Cable) if i want to. So hopefully they would have some type program that would detect IP changes and update accordingly

So i've looked at a variety of registrars so far. The three left were really NameCheap, DreamHost, & DomainMonster.

I have heard good things about DreamHost but i think its off the list because they don't give you any information about the features you get when you register your domain with them. They have a "Whats included" button the page but it mainly list the features with hosting not registration.

DomainMonster looks pretty cool but i don't see anything about subdomains. Also i would assume they don't have a system for dynamic ip address updating. So you would have to constantly check that your ip of your ISP has changed or not and update it manually.

NameCheap also looks nice. There are two things i really like about them. Right on their feature page they list "Free Dynamic DNS With Client" which is pretty cool. They also have a free SSL certificate for the first year. Haven't messed a lot with certificates but this would definitely be something i would use. Only minus i can see is you only get free private whois for the first year. After that its $2.99 which isn't that big of a deal.

I'm leaning towards NameCheap now. Is this a good choice. Is there anything else i should be looking at?

Comment: Won't don't those that downgrade a post leave a comment as to why? Downgrading is saying that isn't a valid question for this site. PLEASE tell me WHY!!!! There is even a tag for domain regitration.

Comment: A vote to close means it isn't valid for this site. A downvote means it's not a good question. I'm not sure why you were downvoted but I can guess that it may have something to do with the rambling going on, something to do with asking more about DNS than registrars, and something to do with the amateur sound of the question.

Comment: Perhaps you would do better at the [Webmaster's Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). This site is for *"people who manage or maintain computers in a professional capacity"* (probably servers and routers) (See the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq)).

Comment: I understand your comment about the "amateurish" tone of my post because it is exactly that. But a lot of people who ask questions ask them because they don't know. How do you learn without asking questions? I hope serverfault hasn't morphed into "you better know what your talking about before you ask a question" or you will be scalded.

Comment: It's not a "you better know what you're talking about..." type of community...It is, however, a site for system administrators and IT professionals...If you sound like an amateur and not a professional, you likely will get scalded.

Comment: @user36914 If you ask a dozen SF users you'll get two dozen answers on this issue of what is or is not a good question. IMO, your post was just fine. A professional IT person would ask it. A tad rambling perhaps, but not worthy of being downvoted. If you stick around, I suspect you'll realize things are mostly fair around here.

Comment: I really want to +1 just for the anti-GoDaddy comment.

Comment: For the record, this isn't a bad question IMO.  Should be on Webmasters.stackexchange.com though.  And probably should be CW.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, I use NameCheap. They are set up to cater to people who deal with more than just a handful of domains. Their bulk actions can really save time if you own a few dozen domain (or a few thousand, as the case may be). Their support is fast too.

They do offer hosting as well, but that doesn't seem to be their bread and butter so take that as you will. Also, their site is consistently slow and is prone to timeouts. I use their cheap email hosting for simple POP3 and it hasn't given me issues.

Now, if hosting is part of what you want, I would recommend SiteGround for shared hosting but not for VPSs. You get raked over white hot coals as far as price is concerned. I don't deal with VPSs much so you'll have to wait for someone else to help you out with recommendations for that.

Answer (score 1):

A domain registrar is what it says on the tin: they register a domain in your name and point it somewhere.

What you're looking for is a hosting provider, irrespective of the services you're looking for. Many registrars also offer a hosting and/or redirection solution to keep you in their list of customers. Otherwise there's no stickiness, and you'll move your domain every year to a cheaper registrar.

For what it's worth, I like GoDaddy for cheap registrations, but Site5 kicks them to the ground for hosting.